# RSSNSA Proxy for isolation

Tags: stream-isolation

I did a lil thing because i want RSS over Tor, but no RSS reader is Tor aware. They fetch everything over one circuit and i do not like this. This is shit.

So here is RSSNSA: https://notabug.org/SuspiciousActions/RSSNSA

RSSNSA works like this:

1. Fetch your RSS feeds with wget
2. Serve your RSS feeds locally
3. Let your RSS reader of choive fetch it locally

There are some Features:

- Supports all (non shit) RSS Readers! (maybe)
- New circuit every fetch!
- Randomized fetching times!
- Spoofed useragent!
- Add Onionsupport for your RSS reader of choice!

My main concern is, that wget produces another fingerprint than your normal RSS reader. But those will produce their own so as long as there is no standardized RSS reader for us Tor users, it is as good as we get.

What do you think of it?

Comment: RE: allow_reuse_address = True According to this you need to derive a class in order to override the default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728912/socketserver-allow-reuse-address-to-rebind-existing-port-number-not-working-wi

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for: some feed and reader combinations will automatically update the source and overwrite the local URL (useful for subscribing to site that has no obvious feed URL but detrimental in this case.)

Some other notes:

In the comments in RSSNSA.py it has 'seconds - hours' in the wrong order above the delay example table.

On startup the program updates all feeds without randomizing. Not ideal. An improvement might be an option to update on startup or not. (I just edited my local copy to my liking).

By changing torport to 9150, you should be able to use an already running Tor Browser rather than starting up tor service separately. Might a nice option for some.

Anyway, nifty little program. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Another concern is that images within feeds will get downloaded and displayed by external readers.Any similar resources will get fetched over the normal network connection.
To prevent this you can use a reader that doesn't fetch anything, strip them out prior to saving the XML, or even fetch the image over Tor, save it, and then modify the XML to point to the local resource then save the XML.